# MVC3: How to check recaptcha with Ajax or directly with JS?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, recaptcha

I would like  to check the recaptcha control via Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Competition/CheckForm',
            type: "POST",
            data: ????,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                return false;
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My problem is, how i can transfer the recaptcha data to my ActionResult.

```
@ReCaptcha.GetHtml(publicKey: "publicKey")
```

Here is my ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckForm(???)
{
    if (ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "privateKey"))
    {
    }
    return Json();
}
```

Anyone have an idea how i can check the recaptcha with Ajax?

It's easy with PHP...there you have the possibility to check the data with a function ("recaptcha_check_answer" from "recaptchalib.php")

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try subscribing to the submit event of the form in order to AJAXify it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

But if you wanted to AJAX submit a given form when some element is clicked other than its submit button you could also do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someButton').submit(function () {
        var myForm = $('#myForm');
        $.ajax({
            url: myForm.attr('action'),
            type: myForm.attr('method'),
            data: myForm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how would the ActionResult look like?

Comment: @lifeofbenschi, that will depend on what you want your action to do. For example you could define a view model which will contain the different input fields of the form and then have your controller action take that model as argument: `public ActionResult CheckForm(MyViewModel model) { ... }`. The `ReCaptcha.Validate` method you are using is correct as it allows you to verify if the user entered the correct captcha value.

Comment: I want to check the recaptcha control and then return the result (correct or false) as json. But i have no idea what data the "Validate" function needs. (The whole form? or specific values?)

Comment: @lifeofbenschi, the Validate method will check in the request the value that the user entered.

Comment: 'code'public ActionResult CheckForm(form ???)'code'...what's the name of the "serialized" object?

Comment: @lifeofbenschi, it's called `recaptcha_response_field` but I wonder why do you need it. The `ReCaptcha.Validate` will automatically validate it without you needing to ever include it as action argument.

Comment: Ok - i made a mistake! (used click instead of submit) :-) your answer worked. thx